# Can't get validation to work on post method

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a form that I want to validate when Title, URL is blank, or Category is not selected and the form will not validate even though I have a validation on the form and viewmodel and If (IsModelState.IsValid). What am I missing?

View

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-7 order-md-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="text-info">@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
            <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <partial name="_ClientStatusMessage" />
                    <form id="form-create-link"
                          method="post"
                          asp-controller="Link"
                          asp-action="CreateLink">

                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <div asp-validation-summary="All" id="validation-error" hidden class="text-danger custom-validation-summary"></div>
                        </div>

                        <input id="link-id" asp-for="@Model.LinkId" type="hidden" />
                        <input name="FetchCategories" type="hidden" />
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @{
                                    var authorizedCommitteeTypes = await Model.CommitteeType
                                        .ToSelectListAsync(AuthorizationService, User, 
             AuthRequirements.AdminCommitteeType);
                                    if (authorizedCommitteeTypes.Count == 1)
                                    {
                                        <input id="committeeType" name="committeeType" type="hidden" 
          value="@authorizedCommitteeTypes.FirstOrDefault()?.Value" />
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <label class="control-label">Committee Type</label>
                                        <select id="add-edit-committee-type"
                                                name="committeeType"
                                                asp-for="@Model.CommitteeType"
                                                asp-items="@authorizedCommitteeTypes"
                                                class="form-control">
                                        </select>
                                    }
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-4">
                            <label class="control-label">Category</label>
                            @{
                                if (Model != null && Model.AvailableCategories != null)
                                {
                                    var availableCategories =
                                        new SelectList(
                                            Model.AvailableCategories.OrderBy(c => c.Order),
                                            dataValueField: "CategoryId",
                                            dataTextField: "Title",
                                            selectedValue: Model.CategoryId);

                                    <select id="dropdown-linkCategories" required
                                            asp-for="@Model.CategoryId"
                                            asp-items="@availableCategories"
                                            class="form-control">
                                        <option>-- Select --</option>
                                    </select>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <select id="dropdown-linkCategories"
                                            class="form-control">
                                        <option>-- Select --</option>
                                    </select>
                                }
                            }
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-4">
                            <label class="control-label">Title</label>
                            <input id="title" asp-for="Title" name="title" class="form-control" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-4">
                            <label class="control-label">Display Order</label>
                            <div>
                                <input id="order" asp-for="Order" name="order" class="form-control" 
                    />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-4">
                            <label class="control-label">URL</label>
                            <input id="url" asp-for="URL" name="url" class="form-control" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                            <textarea class="rtextDescription" name="Description" id="Description" row="1" cols="60"
                                      data-val-maxlength-max="200" asp-for="Description"
                                      data-val-maxlength="Max length for Description is 200"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        @{

                            if (Model.LinkId == 0)
                            {
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <input type="button" id="link-save-and-add-another"
                                           class="btn btn-forum col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4"
                                           value="Add & Create Another" />
                                    <input type="button" id="link-submit"
                                           class="btn btn-forum col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4"
                                           value="Add & Return to Links" />
                                    <a asp-area="Admin"
                                       asp-controller="Link"
                                       asp-action="Index"
                                       class="btn btn-forum col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Back to 
                       Links</a>
                                </div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-12">
                                    <input type="button" value="Save" id="edit-submit"
                                           class="btn btn-forum col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2"
                                           data-action="button" />

                                    <a asp-area="Admin"
                                       asp-controller="Link"
                                       asp-action="Index"
                                       class="btn btn-forum col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Back to Links</a>
                                </div>
                            }
                        }
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 order-md-4">
    @{
        var linkMenuViewModel = new LinkMenuViewModel
        {
            LinkMenu = LinkMenu.ManageLinkCategories,
            LinkId = Model.LinkId
        };
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("LinkSideBarComponent", linkMenuViewModel);
    }
    </div>
 </div>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [AjaxOnly]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateLink(LinkViewModel linkToCreate, CancellationToken 
        cancellationToken)
    {
        // Create a new Link to receive the required properties from the view model
        var newLink = new Link();
             
        var availableCategories = await 
         WhereAdminAuthorizedAsync(_linkService.GetLinkCategories(linkToCreate.CommitteeType))
       .ConfigureAwait(true);
        linkToCreate.AvailableCategories = availableCategories;
        
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save the Link
            try
            {
                _mapper.Map(linkToCreate, newLink);
                newLink.LinkCategory = await _linkService.GetLinkCategoryAsync(newLink.CategoryId, cancellationToken)
                    .ConfigureAwait(true);

                await UseAdminResourceAsync(newLink, async () =>
                {
                    newLink.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                    newLink.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                    await _linkService.CreateEditLink(newLink, User.Identity.Name, 
               cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(true);

                    return RedirectToAction("CreateLink", linkToCreate);
                }).ConfigureAwait(true);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Save failed, add an error message and reload the same page
                TempData.Put(TempDataKey.Link.ADD_MESSAGE, 
             StatusMessageModel.Create(UserStringsService.LinkUpdateFailed, false));
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("CreateLink", linkToCreate);
    }
```

View Model

```
  public class LinkViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a specific/unique ID for a Link (Primary Key --> Integer)
    /// </summary>
    public int LinkId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the title of a Link (Varchar)
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please add a Title.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the URL of a Link (Varchar)
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please add a URL.")]
    public string URL { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the order in which the Link will be displayed (Integer)
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please add a Display Order.")]
    public int Order { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the description of a Link (Varchar)
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a specific/unique ID for a Category
    /// </summary>
    [HiddenInput]
    [DisplayName("Category")]
    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a list of Available Categories
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<LinkCategory> AvailableCategories { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the CommitteeType List
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Committee Type")]
    [ValidCommitteeType(ErrorMessage = "Please select Committee type")]
    public CommitteeType CommitteeType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the bool whether to fetch link categories.
    /// </summary>
    public bool FetchCategories {get; set; }
}
```

How can I get the validation to work on post method?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you use ajax to post the model to the CreateLink action.

If you use ajax it will not fired server-side validate, besides, I found the title's name property is not as same as the LinkViewModel `Title` property, this will also make your application not work well.

```
<input id="title" asp-for="Title" name="title" class="form-control" />
<input id="url" asp-for="URL" name="url" class="form-control" />
```

to

```
<input id="title" asp-for="Title" name="Title" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
<input id="url" asp-for="URL" name="URL" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="URL" class="text-danger"></span>
```

I suggest you could try to use `Jquery Validation` at client side and add `asp-validation-for` as below codes shows:

```
@model LinkViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Link";
}

<h1>Link</h1>



<form id="form-create-link"
      method="post"
      asp-controller="Home"
      asp-action="CreateLink">

    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" id="validation-error"  class="text-danger custom-validation-summary"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-4">
        <label class="control-label">Title</label>
        <input id="title" asp-for="Title" name="Title" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>

        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-12">
            <input type="button" value="Save" id="edit-submit"
                   class="btn btn-forum col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2"
                   data-action="button" />

        </div>
    </div>
</form>


@section Scripts
{
    @*you could also add this partial view*@
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    @*<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>*@
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#edit-submit').click(function () {
                console.log("Fired");
                if ($("#form-create-link").valid()) {
                    console.log("valid");
                    $('#form-create-link').submit();
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Novalid");

                    return false;
                }
            });

            $("#form-create-link").on("submit", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var viewModelobject = {};
                console.log("ajax");
                viewModelobject.Title = $("#title").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/CreateLink",
                    data: JSON.stringify(viewModelobject),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Hello")
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Update:

According to your LinkViewModel's CategoryId property, I found you use int as its type. Since the int doesn't contains null in C#, so the required will never fired. I suggest you could use `[Range(0, int.MaxValue)]` instead. More details, you could refer to below codes.

1.Modify the LinkViewModel as below:

```
    [HiddenInput]
    [DisplayName("Category")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
    //[Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
```

2.Modify the html makeup as below:

Since I don't used your dbcontext, I directly pass a selecetlist to the view.

```
    <select id="dropdown-linkCategories" required
            asp-for="@Model.CategoryId"
            asp-items="@ViewBag.SelectList"
            class="form-control">
        <option>-- Select --</option>
    </select>

    <span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Link()
    {

        //var listView =new LinkViewModel {  Title="aaa"} ;


        var testItems = new List<TestItem> {
           new TestItem{ ItemId=1, ItemName="test1"},
           new TestItem{ ItemId=2, ItemName="test2"},
           new TestItem{ ItemId=3, ItemName="test3"},
           new TestItem{ ItemId=4, ItemName="test4"},
        };


        ViewBag.SelectList = new SelectList(testItems, "ItemId", "ItemName");


        return View();
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I see you added the validation for URL and Title which work but what about for the select dropdown validation? What does that look like?  Since I have a Select as my default value how would I do that?

Comment: According to your LinkViewModel's CategoryId property, I found you use int as its type. Since the int doesn't contains null in C#, so the required will never fired. I suggest you could use `[Range(0, int.MaxValue)]` instead. More details, you could refer to updated answer.